# Override Setter/Getter of a Type

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to override default `setter`/`getter` of a type? I mean is there any way to do this:

```
Class Foo
 public Property Value as string 
End class 

...
dim Foo as new Foo
' instead of
Foo.Value = "SomeString"
' do this
Foo = "SomeString" !!!
```

is it possible at all?

Comment: Are you asking about vb.Net or about c#?

Comment: No, that is not possible.  How would you then distinguish between assigning an object to the variable and setting that property of the object?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Wrong. It is definitely possible in both languages, through implicit operators.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, well, the tags say VB.NET and the code is VB.NET so I guess they mean VB.NET, so I'm interested to see how it would be done.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the title states vb.net/c#. I initially though about default properties for vb.Net, but it turns out it's only for properties that takes a parameter. Check the duplicate I've proposed - it shows how to create an implicit operator in vb.Net.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, the title no longer states that, as tags should not appear in titles anyway.

Comment: Still a duplicate, though....

Comment: @ZoharPeled, would that potential duplicate answer work here though?  This question is asking about setting a property of an existing object, not creating a new object with that property set to that value.  Using `CType` like that, wouldn't you end up with a new `Foo` object and the original one discarded?  That would be a problem for reference types too.

Comment: [C# - Choosing a Default Property or Method for a Class](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/597deb89-35a0-48b1-9d76-8ef1930a4a02/c-choosing-a-default-property-or-method-for-a-class?forum=csharpgeneral). Cumbersome. Useless.

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably be wrong here. While you can create an implicit operator that will convert a string to a new `Foo` with the `Value` property containing that string, you can't use implicit operators on an already existing instance - so that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Jimi, I think that that C# solution has the same shortcoming as the suggested VB solution because it would end up creating a new object of the type with the default property set rather than setting the default property of the existing object.  Maybe that's OK for the OP and they just didn't explain their requirement but, if their description is accurate then I think they're out of luck.

Comment: @jmcilhinney  I forgot to mention Pointless. The important part of that post was the introduction: *Unlike in C++ you cannot overload the = operator in C#. The closest you can come to what you want to do is:(...)* .

Comment: Can't access the property without an object for the class. If you have created shared property they you can access using classname.Property without object creation.

`Class ClassName
 Private Shared iVarProp As Integer
 Public Shared Property VARProp() As Integer
  Get
   Return iVarProp
  End Get
  Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
   iVarProp = value
  End Set
 End Property
End Class

Class MyClient
 Public Shared Sub Main()
  ClassName.VARProp = 25
  
  Dim iVarPropVal As Integer = ClassName.VARProp
  Console.WriteLine(iVarPropVal)
 End Sub
End Class` 
Unable to format code